# Foreach loop to extract text file, from Access datable, using columns from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access, foreach, datatable

What I have to do is create a console application that extracts a single table, from an Access database, using an SQL query in app.config, so that it is possible to change the SQL without changing the code in the application. 
The extracted information has to be in a text file format. The hard part is that I have an Excel file with the mapping of the table and I only need to extract that information, and add some other.

For example, I will need to create a new column that is not originally in the datatable and give it a default value. And that information is in the Excel file.

I already have the connections done and I extracted a table that I need from the Access database, for a temporary datatable. I already have a datatable from the Excel file with only the columns I will need to use in a temporary datatable.

I need to create a foreach loop to check if the A column in Excel is in use. If yes then I need to check another column that contains the name of that column in the Access datatable, if there is a value I need to to extract that column to the text file, if there is no value I need to check another column that contains a default value and I need to add that value to a column that doesn't exist in the database. If there are no values in both those columns than I need to just add a blank space with the width value in the text file.

All these columns extracted to the text file need to have the width-string.width has a blank space between them and there is no need to extract the column names.

This what I have so far:

```
static void createfile(DataTable accessTable, DataTable excelTable)

    {
        string strFileData = "";

        foreach(DataRow accessRow in accessTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow excelrow in excelTable.Rows)
            {
                string fieldname = "";
                fieldname = excelrow["FieldName"] //if it's not empty
                strFileData.insert accessRow[fieldname];
                string test = accessRow[fieldname.ToString()];
                if(position == 0)
                strFileData = strFileData.Insert(0,iNoOf2025.ToString().PadLeft(width, '0'));

            }


            //insert in the text file
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, i already solved the problem, I just needed to create a foreach inside a foreach and specify the operations inside each foreach loop with some if operators.